# Boost stacktrace printing weird file names

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace

I'd like to print a callstack with Boost::stacktrace. I have read official documentation from [Here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html)

Actually I have already done, but I guess there's something wrong about printed file names: it does not them correctly (sometimes file name does not corresponds to the file where the called function is located).

The stack trace that I got from the code that you all can see below:

```
0# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >::init(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) of C:/Users/paceg/Personale/JPL/exception/A.cpp at line 77
1# f2() of C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/stacktrace/detail/frame_unwind.ipp at line 9
2# f() of C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/stacktrace/detail/frame_unwind.ipp at line 5
3# main of C:/Users/paceg/Personale/JPL/exception/Main.cpp at line 4
4# __tmainCRTStartup of C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c at line 268
5# mainCRTStartup of C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c at line 190
6# register_frame_ctor of  at line 0
7# register_frame_ctor of  at line 0
```

As you can see, A.hpp owns f2() and f(), therefore why it is printing frame_unwind?
And f() is called by main() at line 3, not at line 4

A.hpp:

```
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE 
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

extern void f();
extern void f2();
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"

void f(){
    f2();
}

void f2(){

    auto frames = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++){
        std::cout<< std::to_string(i) + "# " + frames[i].name() + " of " + frames[i].source_file() + " at line " + std::to_string(frames[i].source_line())<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"
int main(){
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

task.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Windows Client",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-static",
                "-std=c++23",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Main.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/A.cpp",
                "-no-pie",
                "-fno-pie",
                "-lbacktrace",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/windows/Main.exe"
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: fwiw, I get the same issue with boost's stacktrace using addr2line and header-only version.

Comment: @supernun Actually I ended up developing my own version of Stacktrace wrapper. If you are strill interested, take a look at my project https://www.github.com/Gabriele-P03/JPL. Into utils module, there's a debug section with it